# Decode a utf8 string in python

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, mojibake

I have a problem about encode and decode in Python. I want to encode a plain text in Vietnamese by my algorithm, but this algorithm can't encode a vietnamese plaintext, so I convert it to UTF-8 by `plaintext.encode('utf-8')`, then I convert it from bytes to string (because my algorithm only encodes a string). But my problem is in the decode part, then I decode by my algorithm, I got a UTF-8 string, so I want to decode UTF-8 string to Vietnamese text (mojibake), but I can't use `receiveString.decode('utf-8')` because "string has no attribute 'decode'". I know strings can't use this method but how to handle that?

This is the string I receive:

```
b'v\\xc3\\xb4 \\xc4\\x91\\xe1\\xbb\\x8bch thi\\xc3\\xaan h\\xe1\\xba\\xa1'
```

That's a UTF-8 string, I want to decode it but

```
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: bytes class has the decode attribute: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Comment: If you know what you are doing (it does not look so), you can convert from text to bytes lossley by using a charmap encoding, and then the `.decode` call will work. Do `my_string.encode("latin1").decode("utf-8")`. That is not the only part wrong in there though, so, good luck. Improve the question with actual inputs, desired outputs, Python snippets, and we can help better.

Comment: if you have `string` then first you have to `encode()` to `bytes` and later `decode()` `bytes` to `string`. But if your string starts with `b'` then it can mean you converted it to string in wrong way and you have to remove `b'` at the beginning and `'` at the end before you will encode it from string ot bytes,

Comment: [The XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: Mojibake is a term with a specific meaning - getting incorrect characters because you're using the wrong encoding. I'm not sure you're using it properly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty unclear question. However, the following code snippet could help (inline comments show partial progress report):

```
receive_string = "b'v\\xc3\\xb4 \\xc4\\x91\\xe1\\xbb\\x8bch thi\\xc3\\xaan h\\xe1\\xba\\xa1'"
vietnamese_txt = (receive_string
  .encode()                      # b"b'v\\xc3\\xb4 \\xc4\\x91\\xe1\\xbb\\x8bch thi\\xc3\\xaan h\\xe1\\xba\\xa1'"
  .decode('unicode_escape')      #  "b'vÃ´ Ä\x91á»\x8bch thiÃªn háº¡'"
  .encode('latin1').decode()     #  "b'vô địch thiên hạ'" 
  .lstrip('b').strip("'"))       #    'vô địch thiên hạ'

print(vietnamese_txt)            #     vô địch thiên hạ
```

> ```
> vô địch thiên hạ
> ```